How to define separator characters for argparse?
Python's argparse module is a powerful tool for parsing script command line arguments. The problem is that it expects the args to be separated by spaces. Is there a way to let argparse know I am using a comma-separated args list instead of space-separated args list, especially for the positional args?
For example:
$ python3 myscr.py --arg1 1 --arg2 2 3,4

In this example, 3 and 4 are two required positional args separated by a comma, but the parser will get them as a single positional argument, and possibly throw an error for the missing second arg.
The help for the parse_args() method says it is expecting a list of strings to parse, and where none is provided, it uses sys.argv by default. So a workaround may be to pre-parse sys.argv before calling parse_args(). But this needs explicitly extending the list and making sure not to split comma-separated-substrings that are given inside quotes, etc.

Splitting on spaces is something the shell handles, not something argparse handles. If you wanted to change the separator character, you'd have to change that in your shell.

Right. The shell hands over the array that becomes sys.args. Python lets you do secondary processing on that list, if you wanted to.

But if you want things like "making sure not to split comma-separated-substrings that are given inside quotes", you're not going to be able to handle that on argparse's end, because quotes are a shell thing too. Quotes are gone by the time argparse sees arguments. It can't distinguish between python blah.py 1,2 and python blah.py '1,2'. (And of course, if you want the separator character to be , the command line should really look like python,blah.py,1,2.)

after getting parameters you can always add own code which check if there is , in arguments and split it.

@furas - yes, which is what I mentioned in my original question. I would like to avoid adding my custom code for this.

@user2357112 - you are right about the need for commas between all args, but I mentioned in the question "separators" and not "separator" to cover this. I did not want to dig into all the corner cases in the question's body, so it gets overly clutterred.

That's sys.argv a list of strings provided by the interpreter, based on input from the shell.  args is the commonly used variable name for the result of parse_args()  Life is usually simpler for you and your users if you adapt your input expectations to the system standards.  https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.argv

@hpaulj - thanks for noticing the typo. Question fixed.

If you or some important user is in the habit using a comma (only) separator, it might be simpler to define the positional as nargs='+'.   Then after parsing check that list for strings with comma (or other separator) and split to your heart's content. No one will scold you for a bit of post parsing code.

Thanks. No, this is not the habit. The actual usecase is that I am copying and pasting some of the args into my command line, from the results of another script. So instead of having to delete the comma, I thought it may be possible to let the module know how to treat it the way I want to. Yes, there are multiple ways to work around this problem. I ended up temporarily changing the script that creates the value pairs and changed the printed comma into a space.

adding custom code (like in answer below) could take few minutes, and asking question and waiting for other solutions took you already few hours :) So in my opinion custom code can be simpler and faster solution :) But if someone will show other fast solution then all we can learn something. Frankly in some situations I use custom code because I can create more complex ideas - like use , to separate values and ; to separate groups - 2,3;4,5;3,9

Thanks for your help and for budgeting my time. As noted, the problem was solved in other means. The question remains for posterity, and maybe for motivating the module devs to add  this ability.

And FWIW - the (currently) one answer, although could save the problem, just does not answer the question as asked. There are many ways to skin a cat. Not all of them answer a specific question.

> python test.py --count 5,4
['5', '4']
> cat test.py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import argparse
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('--count')
    val = parser.parse_args().count
    your_list = val.split(',')
    print(your_list)

Don't rely on your libs too much, you can always write your own parser too if your input gets more wack (with sys.argv). Most of the time you're going to need to do a bit of work yourself ;)

Thanks. Upvoted both (current) answers as they provide solutions to the problem, although not directly answering the question.

i gotchu let me pop up the source code its only... 2.6k lines. i think the question you might want to consider asking is should argparse support special delimns, my SE brain tells me it falls out of scope, also the internal methods would be one line, aliasing the split operator. but hey this is python not rust so, who knows -- if i dont get back on this blame argparse programmers

Yeah, the more you think about this, is is probably not best idea to put this on argparse. Thanks.

Occasionally argparse users play with shlex to convert strings to/from argv like lists in a manner that is closer to what the shell does (than the plain astr.split).  I haven't used it much, but here are some ideas from playing around.
import shlex

Take your cmdline string:
In [442]: astr
Out[442]: 'myscr.py --arg1 1 --arg2 2 3,4'

Default split will produce a argv like list.  You may be starting with this in sys.argv.
In [443]: argv = shlex.split(astr); argv
Out[443]: ['myscr.py', '--arg1', '1', '--arg2', '2', '3,4']

If starting with sys.argv, we can recreat the string with join:
In [444]: astr1 = shlex.join(argv); astr1
Out[444]: 'myscr.py --arg1 1 --arg2 2 3,4'

We can get finer control on the split by creating a shlex instance. Look at the shlex.split code to see where I'm going.
In [445]: lex=shlex.shlex(astr1)

It has a whitespace attribute.
In [446]: lex.whitespace
Out[446]: ' \t\r\n'

Modify that by adding a comma to it:
In [447]: lex.whitespace=' \t\r\n\,'

Now split on whitespce:
In [448]: lex.whitespace_split=True    
In [449]: argv1 = list(lex)    
In [450]: argv1
Out[450]: ['myscr.py', '--arg1', '1', '--arg2', '2', '3', '4']

I believe this is the kind of argv that your argparse would handle.
In [461]: parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
     ...: parser.add_argument('--arg1')
     ...: parser.add_argument('--arg2')
     ...: parser.add_argument('posarg', nargs='+');

In [462]: parser.print_help()
usage: ipykernel_launcher.py [-h] [--arg1 ARG1] [--arg2 ARG2]
                             posarg [posarg ...]

positional arguments:
  posarg

options:
  -h, --help   show this help message and exit
  --arg1 ARG1
  --arg2 ARG2

In [463]: parser.parse_args(argv[1:])
Out[463]: Namespace(arg1='1', arg2='2', posarg=['3,4'])

In [464]: parser.parse_args(argv1[1:])
Out[464]: Namespace(arg1='1', arg2='2', posarg=['3', '4'])

That shlex lex instance has a lot more bells and whistles.  I've only touched on the options.

Thanks. I guess this is the kind of functionality I'd like to see embedded in argparse. This and @user2918098's answer suggest methods that will probably work, however, are not what I was looking for in the original question. I upvote both answers anyway.

Interesting wonder - how will this module treat quoted strings that include the separator chars?

It does have some quote options.  Generally shells use quotes to prevent splitting, but I haven't paid much attention to that.
